# pjsip crash in ios 16+ ,xcode 14+

Tags: pjsip, ios16, xcode14

`

```
libsp.dylib`spd_checkin_socket.cold.1:
    0x220ae6364 <+0>:  adrp   x8, 146018
    0x220ae6368 <+4>:  adrp   x9, 0
    0x220ae636c <+8>:  add    x9, x9, #0xa3f            ; "Linked against modern SDK, VOIP socket will not wake. Use Local Push Connectivity instead"
    0x220ae6370 <+12>: str    x9, [x8, #0x2a0]
->  0x220ae6374 <+16>: brk    #0x1
```

`

I add the define in config_site.h, but don't work, the crash also appear.

`#define PJ_IPHONE_OS_HAS_MULTITASKING_SUPPORT 0`

I add the define in config_site.h, but don't work, the crash also appear.

`#define PJ_IPHONE_OS_HAS_MULTITASKING_SUPPORT 0`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [PJSIP Getting Started guide's "iPhone Common Problems" section](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#Commonproblems), this is caused by the deprecation and removal of `kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP` stream type that PJSIP for iOS used to use.

See that document for detailed explanation of the workaround, but generally calling `pj_activesock_enable_iphone_os_bg(PJ_FALSE)`, before creating any transport, should solve your issue.